# Setting Session Variables when image buttons are clicked?

Tags: c#, session-variables, imagebutton, autopostback

I have two image buttons on the page. When either is clicked it needs to set the session variables yesID and NoId before the page is posted back. I tried putting the code in the click events for each button but the page loads again before it runs that code in the click events. How can i set the 2 session variables when either image is clicked?

```
  <div id="MainPics">
        <div id="RightPic">
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="FirstPicMemberNameLabel" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
            </p>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="FirstPicLink" Width="90%" runat="server" 
                onclick="FirstPicLink_Click" />
        </div>
        <div id="LeftPic">
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="SecondPicMemberNameLabel" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
            </p>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="SecondPicLink" Width="90%" runat="server" 
                onclick="SecondPicLink_Click" />
        </div>
        <div id="skip">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LBNoChoice" PostBackUrl="~/default.aspx" ForeColor="White" runat="server">Skip - I Can't Choose</asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code Behind Page

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            Session["yesID"] = 0;
            Session["noId"] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            //Send Session Variables to Database for Storage.

        }    
 }

  protected void FirstPicLink_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Session["yesID"] = 1;
        Session["noId"] = 2;
    }

    protected void SecondPicLink_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Session["yesID"] =2;
        Session["noId"] = 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this logic help?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["yesID"] = 0;
        Session["noId"] = 0;
    }
    //else
    //{
        //Send Session Variables to Database for Storage.
    //}
}

protected void FirstPicLink_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Session["yesID"] = 1;
    Session["noId"] = 2;

    SendSessionVariables(Session["yesID"], Session["noId"]);
}

private void SendSessionVariables(object p, object p_2)
{
    // Your database code here
}

protected void SecondPicLink_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Session["yesID"] = 2;
    Session["noId"] = 1;

    SendSessionVariables(Session["yesID"], Session["noId"]);
}
```

Comment: Will that click event fire before the page is posted back? It seems once an image is clicked the page reloads and then runs the code in the click events.

Comment: No, the postback event handling can NEVER fire before the load event. Do you need to do some refreshing or rebinding after the Click event is done? If so, you can just redirect the response to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the asp.net image button, It usually fires the click event and calls the method if autopostback is not disabled. If you really want to change the session values before the autopostback being hit, Invoke a client side javascript function on the onclientclick event and from that, make an ajax call to a server page where you update the session variable values. Once you get the response from the ajax call (success event) , return true so that the web page continues with the form post back event.

Comment: It seems to refresh the page before it runs the code in the button which is not what i want to happen. Is there a way to run teh code in the click event before the page reloads?

Comment: so there are some problems with your client side javascript. can you post your javascript code ?

Comment: No javascript running at all. just this asp button  <asp:ImageButton ID="SecondPicLink" Width="90%" runat="server"  
                onclick="SecondPicLink_Click" />